# How to apply selectors on queues to topic from SolAdmin

Tags: jms, jms-topic, solace

Right now I have one single topic which has many different types of messages. Lets say Topic1 has messages of type A, B and C. I have three Queues which are subscribed to the topic (QueueA, QueueB, QueueC). I want each queue to consume only the message type it corresponds to but cannot find a way to do so. So far I am only able to subscribe to the topic (which will take every message that is on the topic). I can't seem to find a place on SolAdmin to set the selector for the messages.

I am using SolAdmin version 8.0.1.3 and Solace VMR version 8.0

Answer (score 3):

Selectors act as egress filters on Solace queues. All messages that match the topic subscription will be spooled on the queue but only messages that match a consumer's selector will be sent to that consumer.

Alternatively, you could use a Topic Endpoint. Selectors act as ingress filters on Topic Endpoints. Only messages that match the selector will be spooled on the Topic Endpoint.

There is no way to define selectors from SolAdmin. The selector is defined in the application when the consumer binds a flow to the queue or the topic endpoint.

For more information about selectors in the Solace platform, please see here:
http://docs.solace.com/Solace-Messaging-APIs/Using-Selectors.htm

Comment: The link above is broken. Also one can refer to https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Selectors.htm